# Angular 4 patchValue based on index in FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am looking to update a `formArray` after the user adds a value in an empty created control.

Currently when the user selects to add a new item i build onto the `formArray` with empty values.

```
buildItem(item?: any, key?: any): FormGroup {
  // Item will pass undefined for initial buildItem in onLoad and new items
  let itemName: string;
  let keyValue: string;
  if (item === undefined) { 
     itemName = ''; key = '' }  
  else { 
     itemName = item.name; keyValue = key 
  };

  /**
   * Builds a single item for form group array in the collectionForm.
   */
   return this.formBuilder.group({ 
                item: [itemName || '', Validators.required], 
                properties: { item, key: key } || {} });
}
```

This works fine for the initial creation and the update of items that are already added. The issue is with new items that are added with empty values. When i add a new item i need to add the return key from firebase in the `properties.key`

In the method for the save of that new item i added a `patchValue`

```
this.items.patchValue([{ 
         // item being returned from firebase promise
         item: item.name, 
         properties: { item: item.name, key: item.$key' } 
}]);
```

However the `patchValue` is not  working at all. When i try the update that new value, although the values have been saved to firebase i still get a return for the values as empty or the save values set on the initial `BuildItem()` and not the updated values in the `patchValue`

I see on the angular `FormArray` Documentation that

> It accepts an array that matches the structure of the control, and **will do its best to match the values to the correct controls in the group**. [REF](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html#!#patchValue-anchor)

Does that mean that it might and might not update that value .. it will just do its best to try? I figure if i can add the index for the value that i want to patch then it should not be a issue at all. like with the `removeAt(idx)`

So if i can write something like

```
this.form.patchValue.atIndex(this.idx,[{ 
         item: item.name, 
         properties: { item: item.name, key: item.$key' } 
}];
```

But not sure i can do that .. well pretty sure that it not possible in that form. Is there any way to specifically target the item that gets patched in a `formArray` or am i maybe not understanding this correctly.

I can sort of get away with this by pushing the new value onto the `formArray`

```
this.items.push(this.buildItem(...));
```

however then i have to add

```
this.items.removeAt(this.idx);
```

In order to remove the initial control on the empty build , which does not seem like any sort of good code.

Comment: `this.items.at(index).patchValue(...)` doesn't work?

Comment: @developer033 Yeah it does , thank you, you can add that as an answer.

Comment: Maybe misunderstanding, but why are you creating an empty control first, if you want to set values to it? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 If the collection from the db is empty ( it can allow for an empty list with just a collection name ) then i want to initialize a default empty input when the page loads that the user can add their first value with

Comment: the naming of the collection and the adding collection items are in different views and have a sort of child parent relationship.. because each input in the `FormGroup` is a component which i am trying to create as generic as possible so i can use it site wide

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use [**`FormArray#at`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at) + [**`AbstractControl#patchValue`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#patchValue):

```
this.items.at(index).patchValue(...);
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p297nt)

Comment: A complete example would have made this answer whole.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this simply by creating a new FormControl if you want to update the hole array structure:

```
this.form.setControl('items',  new FormControl(arrayItemsValue));
```

Or by removing all items before updating them :

```
const items = (<FormArray>this.form.get('items'));
 for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     items.removeAt(i);
 }
 this.form.get('items').setValue(arrayItemsValue);
```

Answer (score 6):

As developer033 said:

> Use FormArray#at + AbstractControl#patchValue

But how to? Here's an example:

**In the HTML:**

```
<div formArrayName="alternateEmail" *ngFor="let control of alternateEmail.controls; index as i">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type an alternative email" [formControlName]="i"><input>
</div>
```

**In the class:**

```
get alternateEmail(){  return this.registrationForm.get('alternateEmail') as FormArray }
```

And the actual patch method:

```
patchDynamicFormBlockValue(){
  this.alternateEmail.at(<index>).patchValue('patchmail@gmail.com')
}
```

You can also remove the `as FormArray` and cast just when you need:

`(<FormArray>this.alternateEmail).at(<index>).patchValue('test@gmail.com')`

Answer (score 1):

In TS file use below as an example

```
let taskListArrays = this.projectParentForm.get('TaskList') as FormArray;
        
taskListArrays.controls[rowindex].patchValue({"Email":"contacttotanuj@gmail.com"};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let rows = this.manageOrderForm.get('ordersForm') as FormArray;
    rows.controls[this.index].patchValue({totalAmount:totalPrice});
    this.index = this.index + 1;
```

formarray set value at index

```
((this.form.get('controls') as FormArray).at(index) as FormGroup).get('description').patchValue(item.description);
```