# Pushing elements to reactive forms array results in ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

turns out i have pretty common problem with modern Angular framework and I was not able to resolve it by looking at other questions.

I have a form using reactive forms that has a dynamic part to it. When I click on the button to add new item to the dynamic part, it will throw ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError,

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'disabled: false'. Current value: 'disabled: true'.

I know the problem is in the lifecycle, but im not able to wrap my head around it and resolve it.

Here is my form and add function

```
    public wishlistForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [""],
    creator: [""],
    category: [WishlistCategories.GENERAL],
    description: [""],
    countryCode: [""],
    isForMarketingPurpose: [false],
    password: [{ value: "", disabled: false }],
    products: this.fb.array([this.fb.group(ReactiveWishModel)])
  });

  get products() {
    const products = this.wishlistForm.get("products") as FormArray;
    return products.controls;
  }

  constructor(
    private wishlistService: WishlistsService,
    private router: Router,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    public headerService: HeaderService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.typeOfAction === UPDATE_ACTION_TYPE) {
      this.wishlistForm.get("password").disable();
    }
    this.wishlistForm.patchValue(this.wishlist);

    const products = this.wishlistForm.get("products") as FormArray;
    products.removeAt(0);
    this.wishlist.products.forEach(product =>
      products.push(this.fb.group(ReactiveWishModelFactory(product)))
    );

    this.wishlistForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
      const isDisabled = status === "INVALID" ? true : false;
      this.headerService.setIsButtonDisabled(isDisabled);
    });
  }
  addWish() {
    (this.wishlistForm.get("products") as FormArray).push(
      this.fb.group(ReactiveWishModel)
    );
  }
```

Any suggestion how to avoid this?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz

Comment: You can not give value to wishlistForm in the declare variable. Well, the real tip is make a function that, received data or null and return the formGroup, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651531/error-when-using-setcontrol-or-patchvalue-in-angular-form-array

Comment: @Eliseo Im not sure if i got it correctly, I moved the form creation into function, but that did not help. The error is created in addWish function.