# Inline FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to put an array of formGroups inside array of formGroups:

```
this.myForms = this.dataSource.data.map((item) => {
  return this.fb.group({
    title: [item.title, [Validators.required]],
    payments: this.fb.array([item.payments.map((payment) => {
      return this.fb.group({
        value: [payment.amount, [Validators.required]],
        included_tax_percent: [payment.included_tax_percent, [Validators.required]]
      });
    })
    )]
  });
});
```

How can i get access to payment field in my mat-table?

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="tax">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <span class="companies-list__head">Tax</span>
    </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell
        fxLayout="column"
        fxLayoutAlign="center start"
        *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"
      >
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="(loaded$ | async)"
        [formGroup]="myForms[i]"
      >
        <ng-container
          *ngFor="let payment of element.payments; let j = index"
          >
          <input
            matInput
            formControlName="myForms[i].payments[j].included_tax_percent"
          />
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

If I try this I get an error:

```
Error: src/app/office/components/my-table/my-table.component.html:158:45 - error TS2339: Property 'payments' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the inner form groups like

element.controls.payments

```
<ng-container
        *ngIf="(loaded$ | async)"
        [formGroup]="myForms[i]"
      >
        <ng-container
          *ngFor="let payment of myForms[i].controls.payments.value; let j = index"
          >
          <input
            matInput
            formControlName="myForms[i].controls.payments[j].value.included_tax_percent"
          />
        </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I get error in browser - ERROR TypeError: element_r50.controls is undefined

Comment: I have edited my answer and changed element to myForms[i]. Could you try if this is working

Comment: Thank you! I think its close and now I have this issue
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: payments is a formControl, so its not an array. ideally you have to use FormArrays in this scenario. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: Look at the post. I make a formArray for payments. Still does not work

Comment: I played a little with template and solved it with your and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774503/formgroup-inside-formarray-in-angular-2-reactive-forms post help. Thank you!